# Silverstripe 3.2 - How to manage different lists of the same Dataobjects in ModelAdmin in different tabs

Tags: php, silverstripe, data-objects, modeladmin

I'd like to manage different filtered lists of the same DataObject in ModelAdmin. I have the DataObject "Message" which has a SentbyID and a SenttoID. In ModelAdmin I want to manage two lists. One list with all messages with a certain SentbyID and one list with messages with a certain SenttoID. Can I manage this two lists in different tabs, f.e. "Inbox" and "Outbox"? How can I do this?

I have this so far:

```
class MessageAdmin extends ModelAdmin {

    private static $menu_title = 'Messages';

    private static $url_segment = 'messages';

    private static $managed_models = array (
        'Message'
    );

    public function getList() {
        $currMember = Member::currentUserID();
        $list = Message::get()->filter(array('SenttoID' => $currMember));
        return $list;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overload getEditForm and define a new FieldList containing a TabSet. The SilverStripe Comments module provides a great example this in action, by showing different types of comments (Spam vs. Moderated) in separate tabs within the same ModelAdmin.

Have a look at https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-comments/blob/2.1/code/admin/CommentAdmin.php

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was searching for. Works perfectly!

Comment: Comments doesn't use ModelAdmin but it's own subclass of LeftAndMain. If you don't need much ModelAdmin magic it's a good way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle it through two distinct ModelAdmin, for example renaming MessageAdmin in ReceivedMessageAdmin, and creating a brand new SentMessageAdmin like the following:

```
class SentMessageAdmin extends ModelAdmin {

    private static $menu_title = 'Sent Messages';

    private static $url_segment = 'sent-messages';

    private static $managed_models = array (
        'Message'
    );

    public function getList() {
        $currMember = Member::currentUserID();
        $list = Message::get()->filter(array('SentbyID' => $currMember));
        return $list;
    }

}
```

Comment: So there is no way to manage it in one ModelAdmin? I hoped to avoid too many menu items in the CMS left sidebar...

Comment: Maybe you can extend ModelAdmin functionality, but I think that it will be an overkill task...

Comment: Thank you for you support! I managed it with the Comments module example below. It was not possible with ModelAdmin but with extending LeftAndMain and a custom getEditForm.